# Survey for Feasibility Study (WFM Tool)

Tags: methodology

I´m doing a feasibility study for a proposed Workforce Management tool to see it is worthy invest on that. This tool can integrate several areas or our organization, so i want to make a survey to identify the needs of the areas related to the functionalities of this application. The goal is to determine the possible savings if the organization decides to adopt that solution.

Any ideas of the kind of question can I use on this survey?

The departments are:

- Recruiting
- Planning/MIS
- Payroll Adminstration
- Training and Quality

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you are asking, or how it is a practical program in project management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't usually start with a proposed product and then see where and how it can be used. You usually start with the needs of the various business areas and then investigate which tools fit those needs (and budgets).

The questions on any survey you intend to send must be related to potential benefits the tool brings and how they relate to the business areas. In essence, you are asking "This tool can do [this thing], what areas of your part of the business could benefit from [this thing]?"

When you have a map of possible benefits (and disbenefits of deploying the tool- not all impacts will be positive) you then need to drill into each and understand in more detail what benefits or problems

Unfortunately, since I have no idea what it means to "integrate several areas of our organisation" nor what a workforce management tool actually does, and since no-one here will have any context for what your organisation does and how such a tool could benefit your specified departments, provision of any more specific responses will be off-topic as "Opinion-based".

Comment: you´re right @MarvMills, maybe my scenario demands a long explanation and dialogue about the situation, but your considerations helped me to start. Thanks!